# How to get the current date formatted through Cmd prompt

Tags: windows, cmd, dos

How to change the date format of today's date in Command prompt
I am trying to fetch the current date using `%date%`
but i want to format the date as `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the formatting you want, you need to parse the output.

`for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %i in ('date /t') do echo %k-%i-%j`

Comment: I'd strongly advise against this, as the code will stop working when your regional settings change.

Comment: I've used it without a problem for about a two decades now, so I'm not too worried ;-)

Comment: That's fine, but bear in mind that people finding this question might try building a batch file that has to run robustly on customer machines where you have no control over those things. Parsing output also can break down with certain locales that include non-ASCII letters in their date format.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable using date.exe (part of [UnxUtils](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnxUtils)) there is a related answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1951681/422842